# Passing data between UIViewController and UIView by property was nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to passing data from **UIViewController** to **UIView**.Here's part of my code:
In my **UIViewController.m**,I define a **scrollview**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)DetailScrollView *scrollView;

- (DetailScrollView *)scrollView{
if (!_scrollView) {
    DetailScrollView *scrollView = [[DetailScrollView alloc] init];
    _scrollView = scrollView;
}
return _scrollView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
  self.scrollView.product = self.product;
}
```

I add a break point hereI.It does get the product value.But in my **DetailScrollView.m** file,the product value was nil.
**DetailScrollView.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)Product *product;
```

**DetailScrollView.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
     //get the value of self.product was nil
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: it is fine but where u are initializing the scrollview?

Comment: @AndeySatyanarayana I use a initialize method

Comment: How did you know you were not getting the product from scrollView? where did you log? viewDidLoad? viewDidAppear?

Comment: @Joshua I add a breakpoint in initWithFrame method of scrollView,It didn't get the product value.

Comment: You can't expect the `product` property to be set in the Initializer. The Initializer will be called in the `addSubView` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want `product` in initializer of your `DetailScrollView`. You won't get that unless you pass it when initializing it. E.g.

```
- (DetailScrollView *)scrollView{

    if (!_scrollView) {
        DetailScrollView *scrollView = [[DetailScrollView alloc] initWithProduct:self.product];
        _scrollView = scrollView;
    }

    return _scrollView;
}
```

Then in initialiser store it as the property:

```
- (instancetype)initWithProduct:(Product *)product {
    self = [super initWithFrame:<#someDefaultFrame#>];
    self.product = product;
}
```

Comment: Can I pass the product in initWithFrame method of scrollView?

Comment: `initWithFrame:` is designated initialiser for any `UIView`, thus you can make your convenience initialiser with product and call `initWithFrame:` from there by defining some default frame. Just like in my provided example.